# AWS SSM describe_instance_information using old data?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I have a lambda function that is running:

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
print(ssm.describe_instance_information())
```

It returns 6 instances.  5 are old instances that have been terminated and no longer show up in my console anymore.  One instance is correct.  I created an AMI image of that instance and tried launching several instances under the same security group and subnet.  None of those instances are returned from describe_instance_information.  Is it reporting old data?9

My end goal is to have the lambda function launch an instance using the AMI and send a command to it.  Everything works if I use the existing instance.  I am trying to get it to work with one created from the AMI.

EDIT:
After a while, the instances did show up, I guess it takes a while.  I dont understand why terminated instances still show up.  I can poll describe_instance_information until the instance_id I want shows up but is there a cleaner built-in function, like wait_for_xxxxx()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter parameter with PingStatus which determine Connection status of SSM Agent.

```
 response = client.describe_instance_information(
    Filters=[
    {
        'Key': 'PingStatus',
        'Values': [
            'Online'
        ]
    },
   ]
)
```

Comment: I realize i can do that, I'm just wondering why terminated instnaces which I no longer have in my console are still showing up.  I did eventually find the new instances.  I guess they take a little time to show up.  Is there a function to more gracefully wait?  right now i'm polling describe

Comment: this command can return instances in the following states:state. Valid states are: Running, Pending, Stopped, Stopping. Invalid states are: Shutting-down and Terminated.

Comment: The terminated ones show "PingStatus": "ConnectionLost".  The connection will never be restored.  does this mean the entries will stay there forever?

Comment: I think when you use  client = boto3.client('ssm') you call system manager api not EC2 api and it seems that ssm keeps the history of all agents (online or ConnectionLost), so I think you may use client = boto3.client('ec2')  with  client.describe_instances() to get more useful information about EC2 instances